# add columns that are not in dataframe but present in another index

Tags: python, pandas

Assume I have a dataframe with several named columns

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': [1, 2], 'bar': [3, 4]})
```

I also have some index of names:

```
all_columns = pd.Index(['foo', 'baz', 'bar', 'quux'])
```

What I want is to add empty columns to `df` with column names from `all_columns` that are not present in `df` yet. So the desired output is:

```
   bar  foo  baz  quux
0    3    1  NaN   NaN
1    4    2  NaN   NaN
```

I'd like to do it in method-chaining style, preserving original dataframe, so I'm looking for something like:

```
df.some_magick_column_appender(all_columns)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `reindex`

```
df.reindex(columns=['foo', 'baz', 'bar', 'quux'])
Out[659]: 
   foo  baz  bar  quux
0    1  NaN    3   NaN
1    2  NaN    4   NaN
```